# Is it possible to exclude specific build variant when using flavor Dimensions?

Tags: android, gradle

When using Gradle flavorDimensions, is it possible to exclude specific variants? 
For example -

```
android {
...

flavorDimensions "abi", "version"

productFlavors {
    freeapp {
        flavorDimension "version"
        ...
    }

    x86 {
        flavorDimension "abi"
        ...
    }
}
```

the following build variants will be created:

x86-freeapp-debug
x86-freeapp-release
arm-freeapp-debug
arm-freeapp-release
mips-freeapp-debug
mips-freeapp-release
x86-paidapp-debug
x86-paidapp-release
arm-paidapp-debug
arm-paidapp-release
mips-paidapp-debug
mips-paidapp-release

Can "mips-paidapp-release" be manually removed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Gradle 0.9 you can apply a variant filter and iterate over them:

```
productFlavors {
    freeapp {
        dimension "version"
    }

    x86 {
        dimension "abi"
    }

    paidapp {
        dimension "mips"
    }
}

// Loop variants
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    // Loop flavors
    variant.getFlavors().each { flavor ->
        println variant.buildType.name + " " + flavor.name + " " + flavor.dimension
        if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release') &&
                flavor.name.equals('paidapp') &&
                flavor.dimension.equals('mips')) {
            variant.setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: that I changed `flavorDimension` to `dimension` because the latter is now the preferred way specify it.

Note2: the above note requires you to use the newer gradle version:

`Project/build.gradle` should have the following:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

while `Project/app/build.gradle` should have this:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where does it says flavorDimention is the preferred way? It doesn't compile when I use it. I don't have I way to get the dimension of the flavor in the loop.

Comment: @user1787773 in your app's gradle.build file make sure you have `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` and in the gradle.build of your project (not your app) make sure you use the newer 1.2.3 gradle version: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it:

```
flavorDimensions "device", "server"

productFlavors {
    emulator {
        dimension = "device"
    }
    phone {
        dimension = "device"
    }
    staging {
        dimension = "server"
    }
    production {
        dimension = "server"
    }
}

android.variantFilter { variant ->
    def device = variant.getFlavors().get(0).name
    def server = variant.getFlavors().get(1).name
    def isRelease = variant.buildType.name.equals('release')
    def isDebug = variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')

    // Disable emulatorProductionRelease build variant
    if (device.equals('emulator') && server.equals('production') && isRelease) {
        variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

I like it because it's easy to read and you can target specific build variants.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that builds upon previous answers, but allows you to specify the variants as a whitelist in a data structure.

```
List<Map> validVariants = [
    [
            dimension1: 'foo',
            dimension2: 'alpha',
    ],
    [
            dimension1: 'bar',
            dimension2: 'beta',
    ],
]
variantFilter { variant ->
    if (validVariants.find { Map validVariantMeta ->
        boolean mismatch = variant.flavors.find { flavor ->
            return validVariantMeta.get(flavor.dimension) != flavor.name
        }
        return !mismatch
    } == null) {
        variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```